# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input in ng-bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap, ngmodel

I have a separate component where I have the ng-bootstrap modal. i am triggering the modal from another component and I am passing it an Input.

So in the modal I have `@Input() board`;

Everything seems to be ok as I am getting the board input in the modal, but whenever I try to bind it with ngModel I get this error: ***Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'***

I do have FormsModule imported.

This is the code where it errors:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="board.name">
```

If I do `{{ board.name }}` it prints the name correctly.

Comment: Is the FormsModule imported in the same `module` where this component is declared?

Comment: Yes it is imported in the same module where the component is declared. I even tried to imported in the main app.module. Same thing...

Comment: Try restarting your app if you haven't already since importing the forms module `ng serve ...` or `npm start`

Comment: I have done that. I really don't understand what the issue is, because I have other components which are importing the FormsModule and the ngModel is working fine.